# Android: Right web hosting for a mobile app

Tags: php, android, web-services, web-hosting

My app comes with preloaded data. At the moment, I have a txt file inside the 'raw' folder. The file has around 1MB of sql commands that are processed when the app starts for the first time. 
I want to have some sort of a web-service that I could call and download this file (instead of attaching it to the apk). I have created few web-services in PHP in the past. However, this time, I have to think about the reliability of the service because my app has around 70,000 downloads a month and it's rising.

Could you tell me what type of the web hosting would be ideal in my case? Does normal 'unlimited hosting' would be reliable and efficient enough? What should I consider when buying the the right web-hosting?

Thank you,
marqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. Most cheap web hosting companies that offer 'unlimited' bandwidth usually have some fair use limit in there.

There are two ways you could go, since you only really need file hosting and not full web-hosting

**Server: Virtual Private, Dedicated, or [Grid-Service](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/gs/)**

- Look for a company that offers a good uptime guarantee
- Make sure they're clear about bandwidth/pricing - you don't want to be charged enormous amounts if you get a moderate spike in downloads.

**Content Delivery Network**

These exist purely to serve content, and serve it fast. Most will have servers in a variety of locations that will cache your content in order to serve it to local users quickly.

Answer (score 0):

'Unlimited' hosting is *always* a bad idea. Seriously, no matter how it's branded (unmetered or whatever) it will always come back to bite you, generally as part of an SLA or simply hidden charges.

I personally think that your best option would be to stick the file on the cloud. Take a look at Amazon's services, specifically S3. This would probably the best and most cost-effective option for you.

Of course, this only applies if you are serving that file (or any other static file). If you're looking for more dynamic options you could still take a look at cloud computing where you'll essentially get a virtual server that's charged by the hour that it's on.

70,000/mo isn't really that much traffic for a single file, but any more is definitely not suitable for a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Actually, unmetered isn't so bad. I know a few dedicated server hosts who offer unmetered bandwidth, but restrict service after a certain amount of usage, offering (but not forcing) an extra payment to re-enable full bandwidth. But 'unlimited' when it comes to storage and transfer on a cheap/budget host is really bad. How can a server physically store 'unlimited' amounts of data, think ^_^